# How can I set the stylesheet of a certain element of Qmessagebox

Tags: qt, stylesheet, messagebox

I have made a QMessageBox in the following way:

```
msgBox.setText("Are you sure?");
msgBox.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox::Yes| QMessageBox::No);
msgBox.setStyleSheet("background-image: url(image)");
msgBox.exec();
```

Unfortunately using setStyleSheet on the messagebox sets the background for the buttons, the textbox and the actual msgbox. This is not wat I want. I want only the msgbox to have a background not the other components of the messagebox. I found out that using:

```
msgBox.button(QMessageBox::Yes)->setStyleSheet(...)
```

can be used to set the background on just the buttons. Is there a command with which I can set just the background of the msgBox, without adding a background to the buttons and the textbox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can limit to which elements the style will be applied by using a selector. So to only apply the style to the `QMessageBox` itself and not its children, you would use:

```
msgBox.setStyleSheet("QMessageBox { background-image: url(image) }");
```

For more details, see [The Style Sheet Syntax - Selector Types](http://qt-project.org/doc/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types).

Comment: In your case, the answer really is: if everything else fails, read the documentation like you would read a book. I've found that at least in case of Qt, there's no substitute for just reading through it all at some point in one's life. You'll keep on missing stuff like that unless you really read it. Page by page. Use a web browser and bookmarks/history to keep track of what you've read through.